# Can we customize app_offline.htm in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've seen some old discussions about this but I couldn't find any reliable information about VS2010 specifically. Has MS added the ability to customize the auto-generated app_offline.htm file (during publish) in the 2010 version?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file VS uses here:

```
file:///C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/VisualStudio/10.0/app_offline.htm
```

That's all I know, good luck